# Expanding html for safari debugger iPad / iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, debugging, safari, inspect-element

Is there a way to expand in a fast way the html in inspect element for safari?
How my situation looks like: http://d.pr/i/43ke

If you debug in your browser you can right-click on your element, and inspect it. When you're on iPad you can't, so i want to expand my html immediately (with a shortcut or something?)

Quite hard to explain tbh.

Comment: Seems like there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + click (on a mac) does the trick partly. It opens up the div + first subdivs.